# Finding all records between date1 and (date2 + 1) in MySql

Tags: mysql, date, increment

Is there any way to find all records in `MySql Query` between 2 dates where we want to increment 2nd date by 1.

Suppose user inputs `Date1 as 2017-04-01` and `Date2 as 2017-04-25` but here I always want to take `Date2` after incrementing it by 1 Day i.e. `Date2 as 2017-04-26` here.

Please let me know if possible?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904597/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-between-date1-and-date2-using-mysql?rq=1

Comment: @Abi: regarding the use of inline code formatting in your suggested edit, please only use that on code or console I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function to add one day to the upper date in your range:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND DATE_ADD('2017-04-25', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Or just `AND '2017-04-25' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`, which renders the same way