# Check if Date is between two dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql record with the columns start_date and end_date. Now I have a date (as example 2017-08-03) and i want to ask if this date is between the start_date and end_date in my mysql table.

Is this possible?

Comment: select * from tab where start_date<='2017-08-03' and end_Date>='2017-08-03'

Comment: You can use WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date BETWEEN start_date_field AND end_date_field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: Select all data between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates)

Comment: Instead of naively asking “is this possible”, next time please just type your question title into Google ... And please go read [ask] - among other things, it explains to you what minimal effort you are expected to make _before_ asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date is between date1 and date2 using mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904597/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-between-date1-and-date2-using-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use between:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
  WHERE '2012-01-18' between start_date AND end_date
```

BTW: Take care of time part if start and end are datetime types

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
  WHERE start_date<='2012-01-18'
  AND end_date>='2012-01-18'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `yourtable`
WHERE (your_found_date BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date')
```